# EDSDK dlls not found in release

Tags: c#, dll, edsdk

I'm developing a program that connects to a canon camera! I've filled the application in canon site and they have sent me the EDSDK dlls!
My program works fine, but when I try to run it in release to get the exe it's not able to locate the EDSDK dlls. I've checked the dlls are both in bin/release and bin/debug and the path is also correct!
Do you have any idea what is going wrong?
Thank you in advance!
PS: I'm using C# by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put **all** DLLs into the same directory as your main assembly (without the sub directories you got) – not only the `EDSDK.dll`.

I added a `lib` subdirectory to my project and added all DLLs (without any further sub directories) and marked them as "copy if newer". With a post-build event I move them after build from `bin\debug\lib` to `bin\debug`:

```
move $(TargetDir)lib\*.dll $(TargetDir)
```

Note: according to the DLLs readme file, it is recommended to use the 32 bit DLLs.